# Why i have White Texture?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, texturing, node-editor

I am trying to make this sphere using two different textures following a tutorial online

[image]

However when I try to add the second texture it becomes white

[image]

Comment: You add values of the second texture on top of the first texture. Color values become nearer to 1 which is white. So it's quite expected behaviour. I would suggest not to add image textures on top of each other at all, adding is often done on masks used for mixing textures.

Comment: It is unclear what you are trying to achieve. Please edit the question and explain it in more detail.

Comment: you see the first picture ? i am trying to make that sphere, its made of 2 textures of bricks ok ?  when i add the first texture to the sphere it's fine(it's clear and red),now when i add the second layer (with different brick texture) instead of giving me the original color of the texture it give me White Version of it

Comment: How do your textures look? What do you wish adding the second texture to the first one to do?